# How to attach values from an array to another key in another array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm using laravel query-builder to get data from database but what I need is just based on php.

Here's some code:

```
$data = DB::select('SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY created_at DESC'):
foreach ($data as $rows) {
    $teacher = DB::select('SELECT name FROM teachers WHERE id = ?', [$row->teacher_id]);
    $data->teacher = $teacher; 
}
return $data;
```

The $data variable has the following array:

```
array:4[
    0 => {
        "id":3
        "teacher_id": 2
    }
    1 => {...some similar keyvalue pairs}
    2 => { ...another key-value pairs}
]
```

So the question is that I want the teacher name from the database to be attached to each   `$data` array iteration by using the `id` from each `$data` iteration to get the teacher name from the second query.

Does anyone get this?

Comment: You need to follow docs [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) so that you can relate your models and eager load the required data don't perform queries inside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this issu using a single query  ..

```
SELECT news.*, teachers.name 
FROM news
INNER JOIN  teachers where teachers.id = news.teacher_id
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```